# Enviar correo si se cumple la condición

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una base de datos que recibe valores de unos sensores (Ej. temperatura), esta base de datos recibe dicho datos cada 20 segundos, mi objetivo es enviar un correo electrónico cada que el valor del sensor de temperatura pase lo 26 °C, después de que sea enviado el programa debe se detenido por 10 minutos, ya que si no se detiene enviara el correo mientras el valor del sensor de temperatura se mantenga arriba de 26 °C. El correo es enviado correctamente pero los dos siguiente problemas:

1° El programa no se detiene, cuando empieza la ejecución del programa, se empiezan a enviar correos sin limite mientras el valor se mantiene arriba de 26°C.

2° Aunque el valor sea menor o mayor de 26 se envia.

**Código para enviar el correo:**

```
def func1(x):
    dataSQL = []

    sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'DB')
    cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT value FROM sensorParser where sensor='TC'")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        dataSQL.append(list(row))
        labels = ['value']
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataSQL, columns=labels)
        Y = df['value'].astype(float)


        if ((Y) > 26.00).any():
            email = 'correo@gmail.com'
            password = 'pass'
            send_to_email = 'correo2@gmail.com'
            subject = 'ALERTA!!!!'
            message = 'Los valores de las variables criticas han superado el limite'
            file_location = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\prograpython\\image.jpg'

            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = email
            msg['To'] = send_to_email
            msg['Subject'] = subject

            msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

            filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
            attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload((attachment).read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

            msg.attach(part)

           server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
           server.starttls()
           server.login(email, password)
           text = msg.as_string()
           server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
           server.quit()
    reactor.callLater(20, func1, "hello")

reactor.callLater(20, func1, "hello")
reactor.run()
```

Saludos.

Comment: Sin haberlo mirado muy a fondo, me llama la atención el `if((Y)>26.0).any()`. Esto comprueba si _cualquier_ valor de esa columna es mayor de 26. Ya que entiendo que la columna es un "histórico" donde se van guardando todos los valores del sensor, tanto tan pronto como aparezca por primera vez el 26 y quede almacenado en esa columna, la condición ya será siempre cierta. En lugar de mirar si _cualquier_ valor es 26 deberías mirar sólo si el _último_ valor es 26, no? En cuanto a lo de esperar 10 minutos ¿dónde haces eso?

Comment: Asi es, debería de mirar solo el ultimo valor es 26, sabes como podría realizar eso?. Aquí: "reactor.callLater(20, func1, "hello")", aqui le estoy diciendo que llame la función cada cierto tiempo y luego se detenga, en este caso 20 seg.

Comment: Pues digo yo que `if Y[-1] > 26.00:` mirará sólo el último valor ¿no? Por otro lado veo que lo del `callLater()` lo haces siempre, tanto si enviaste el email como si no. Quizás deberías tener una variable, digamos `intervalo`, que indique cuánto esperar a la siguiente llamada, con el valor `20` inicialmente, pero que lo pongas a `60` tras enviar un email (y de nuevo a `20` si la última temperatura es inferior a 26). Al final harías `reactor.callLater(intervalo, func1, "hello")`